# onclick handling for jQuery combo box option item

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

```
<option value='0'>Choose A Product</option>
<option id='custAddNewCategory' value='addnew' data-icon='glyphicon glyphicon-plus text-success'>Add new</option>
<option value='769'>1</option>
<option value='770'>1</option>
<option value='773'>1</option>
```

i have this option list generated by jquery code when the page loads.

When the second option 'add new' is clicked, i want  something to be processed.
i tried following, but it fails. :(

```
//custAddNewCategory
$(document).on("click", 'custAddNewCategory', function(e) {
   alert('add new category clicked!');
});
```

do advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select **change** event handler as below:

```js
$('select').on('change', function(event){
if($(this).val() == $('#custAddNewCategory').val()){
alert('add new');
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value='0'>Choose A Product</option>
<option id='custAddNewCategory' value='addnew' data-icon='glyphicon glyphicon-plus text-success'>Add new</option>
<option value='769'>1</option>
<option value='770'>1</option>
<option value='773'>1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').find('option').click(function (){
    var valueSelected = optionSelected.val();
     if(valueSelected) =="addnew"){
           yourFunction();
     }
});
```